# Bullet points do not appear (in \itemize environment with Hebrew font David CLM)

Tags: fonts, symbols, lists, itemize, hebrew

I am writing Hebrew using the David CLM font (from [Culmus](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/)). Using this font there are no bullet points in `\itemize` environments. I do not understand why. It works as it is supposed to work with other fonts. I thought all that stuff was independent from the actual font!

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[14pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{David CLM}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item למה
\item אין פה
\item נקודות?
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like your font does not have a symbol for `\textbullet`.  A quick hack is to take it from another font, for example, using `enumitem` to globally redefine the label of `itemize`,

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label={\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\textbullet}}
```

This uses `\textbullet` from Computer Modern Roman on the first level of `itemize` (since `itemize,1` above).  You might want to experiment with other symbols on this and other levels of the list.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the workaround, but someone should really address this by default.